# PIE.htc is not getting applying for ie 7 and 8 when rails app is deployed using sub uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, passenger, css3pie

Am using rails sub uri (apache2 + passenger) to deploy the application. All css, javascripts and images are working fine. But I am using PIE.htc for rounded corners and box shadow for IE 7 and 8 browsers. It is working fine if we use particular port (9900) but if we use sub uri concept to deploy. It is not working. I am using ie6_fixer gem for this

My css code is

```
.content_row button, #seemore input {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    behavior: url(/javascripts/ie6_fixer/PIE.htc);
    *behavior:url(/PIE/PIE.htc);
}
```

PIE.htc path is public -> javascripts -> ie6_fixer/PIE.htc

Am accessing it abc.com/suburi. But corners are not getting round and shadow is not applying. Please help me to slove this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by giving suburi + PIE.htc path. Please refer the below code

```
.content_row button, #seemore input {
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    behavior: url(/suburi/javascripts/ie6_fixer/PIE.htc);
    *behavior:url(/suburi/PIE/PIE.htc);
}
```

Now if you access abc.com/suburi in IE 8 and 7. Rounded corners and border shadow will gets apply